# On Windows10, do files transit through systemA when from Windows systemA I initiate a file copy from \\systemB\c$\folder1 to \\systemB\c$\folder2

Tags: windows, file-transfer

Do files transit through systemA when from Windows systemA I initiate a file copy from \systemB\c$\folder1 to \systemB\c$\folder2?

It's not a big deal when files are small and not numerous, but otherwise, is it worth remoting to the machine? Or is Windows smart enough to just order systemB to do the copy operation itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a copy, the files travel though system A, but in RAM. No local copy on disk. You will save time with big or numerous files if you remote in to system B. If the source and target are on the same share, moving (rather than copying) a file does not require a round-trip, because the OS only updates the references in the file system.

Comment: Copying within the same share _might_ not need a round-trip either – I think SMBv3 has some support for server-side copy now (of course as long as the client is smart enough to ask).

Answer (score 1):

The copy command works in the computer in which it was invoked.
So, yes, this may be slow; Windows is not smart and will obey commands to the letter.

For a big file, it's worthwhile to remote login to systemB for doing the copy.